# Different spark.sql.shuffle.partitions for each StreamingQuery in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I know how to set it globally, but how to set different

```
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions
```

config for each StreamingQuery in Spark Structured Streaming within the one application (one sparkSession)?

In our case:
We have multiple Streaming Queries using same SparkSession. Each streaming query has own checkpoint location. The queries are running continuously ends with

```
sparkSession().streams().awaitAnyTermination();
```

Thank you

PS I know that I need to clean up checkPoint locations after changing     `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`

Comment: Not sure if that would work, but you can try to override Spark options when defining the stream: `.writeStream.format(...).option("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "400").start()`.

Comment: Not sure about this, but looks like I got it actually working. If we set new value for "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions" on global level it will be applied to the new added streaming queries and will be saved in the checkpoint locations. Existing streaming queries will be not affected.

Comment: They won't be affected unless you need to clear the checkpoint which can happen if you make a state incompatible change to your query. So, I wouldn't rely on this logic. Did you try setting shuffle partitions per query as @Kombajnzbożowy suggested?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by changing the global `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` config value before starting each of the queries.

Assuming you have three streaming queries, query1, query2 and query3, you can do something like this:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 1)
query1.start()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 4)
query2.start()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 8)
query3.start()
```

It's a better approach than suggested in the comment, as you can clear your checkpoints and the number of partitions per query will remain the same.